# How to filter JSON array elememts by type of value?

Tags: json, postgresql

Postgres 12, column contains **sample** json from Quill Editor like:

```
{
    "ops": 
    [
    {
        "insert": "Text 1"
    }, 
    {
        "insert": {"video":"..."}
    },
    {
        "insert": "Text 2"
    }, 
    {
        "insert": {"image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,..."}
    }]
}
```

To get result as `Text 1 Text 2`, meaning filter out (ignore/skip) all `"insert": {"video":"..."}` and `"insert": {"image":"..."}` if presented.

Operators like checking `::json ?| array['video', 'image']` or deleting `::jsonb-'video'` seem helpful, but pg doesn't do one-line if-then-else `(condition)?true_value:false_value`. How to utilize them in this function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fun(
    j json)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' immutable
AS $BODY$
begin
  return string_agg((obj->>'insert') || ' ', '')
  FROM json_array_elements(j->'ops') obj;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fun(j json)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT string_agg(elem ->> 'insert', ' ')
FROM   json_array_elements(j -> 'ops') elem
WHERE  json_typeof(elem->'insert') <> 'object';
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=09f2f78e7e8ab55a0e3bbc7d2b51e1c5)*

After unnesting with `json_array_elements()` like you already had, check the type of the *value* for the *property name* 'insert' with  [`json_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) (not for the nesting object which is always an *object*).

I use a simple SQL function for the simple task.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you want to identify and select both elements `{"insert": "Text 1"}` and `{"insert": "Text 2"}` from the json array value associated to the key `"ops"` :

**Identify and select the elements by their position in the json array :**

```
  return j#>>'{ops,0,insert}' || ' ' || j#>>'{ops,2,insert}' ;
```

**Identify and select the elements by their json type which is 'string' :**

```
  return string_agg(obj->>'insert', ' ')
  FROM json_array_elements(j->'ops') obj
  WHERE json_typeof(obj) = 'string' ;
```

**Identify and select the elements by their json type which is not 'object' :**

```
  return string_agg(obj->>'insert', ' ')
  FROM json_array_elements(j->'ops') obj
  WHERE NOT json_typeof(obj) = 'object' ;
```

This last example do not select the elements whose value is a json object whatever the "key" and "value" inside this json object are.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Data provided is an example, `video` and `image` can be anywhere, or not exits.

Comment: OK so what is your criteria to select the json objects in the json array associated to the "ops" key ?

Comment: To filter-out (ignore) all `"insert": {"video":"..."}` and `"insert": {"image":"..."}`, result for the sample above will be `Text 1 Text 2`.

Comment: @EdouardH. I realize you were close. Just missed one level of nesting.